# Getting NullPointerException while putting data in hashtable

Tags: java

I have invoked the web service method which gives the list of students information.

```
StudentsInfo si = getInfo(username, rollno, class); // web service method invoked
Hashtable hashStudList = new Hashtable();
int size = si.getInfo().size();

for (int i=0;i<size;i++) {
    StudentsList st = new StudentsList();
    String ID = si.getInfo().get(i).getStId().toString();
    st.setId(ID);
    st.setName(si.getInfo().get(i).getStName().toString());
    st.setAddress(si.getInfo().get(i).getStAddress().toString());
    st.setPhone(si.getInfo().get(i).getStPhone().toString());
    // ...
    hashStudList.put(ID, st);
}
```

StudentsList is the bean class containing getter and setter.
But it gives null pointer exception at

```
String ID = si.getInfo().get(i).getStId().toString();
```

while executing it.

Comment: Something is `null`. Post a stack trace or tell us which line it happens on.

Comment: Don't use Hashtable... [It is deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139937/why-is-the-hashtable-class-deprecated) Use HashMap instead, and the Map interface.

Comment: where the nullpointer is thrown?

Comment: I would guess that your getInfo is not working, and you get null. And the si.getInfo().size(); is throwing your nullpointerexception.

Comment: You should probably log your web service response and check if the required data was received or not.

Answer (score 3):

`NullPointerException` is thrown, when you try to access a method or variable of an instance of a class, but there is not really an instance present - so your object you want to work on is `null`.

Take for example this line:

```
                String ID = si.getInfo().get(i).getStId().toString();
```

This can go wrong in a couple of places:

```
                String ID = si.getInfo().get(i).getStId().toString();
        // Possible nulls     ^         ^      ^         ^
```

- `si` can be `null` -> can't invoke `.getInfo()` on it
- the value returned by `getInfo()` is `null` -> can't invoke `.get(i)` on it
- the value returned by `get(i) is`null`-> can't invoke`.getStd()` on it
- the value returned by `getStd()` is `null` -> can't invoke `.toString()` on it

All this would throw a `NPE` on the same line.

It is not nice, but you should to check all these for `null`, one by one. Depending on the business logic, you might want to handle some cases differently, e.g throw some kind of exception when one of them is null, etc...

```
if(si!=null) {
  StudentInfo info = si.getInfo; //using local variable to store value for readability
  if(info!=null) {

    //... and so on
  }
  else {
     throw new MyBusinessException("Info must not be null!");
  }
}
```

Also, this might be a fine choice to reduce the duplication in your code. You don't have to write out all this `si.getInfo().get(i).getStId().` each time: you can use local variables to store the in-between values of the navigation.

**Hashtable**

Hashtable is an old thing, you should not use for new stuff. It is deprecated. Instead of that, please use the [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface and the appropriate implementation for this use case: the [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) class. Also, through generics, it offers a lot more convenient syntax, leaving out casting.

```
Map<String, StudentList> myMap = new HashMap<String, StudentList>();
.... 

myMap.put(id, studentList);
```

**Also recommended for consideration**

- [Java naming convention -- how to name variables and methods](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)
- [Java generics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java)

Answer (score 1):

```
st.setName(si.getInfo().get(i).getStName().toString());
st.setAddress(si.getInfo().get(i).getStAddress().toString());
st.setPhone(si.getInfo().get(i).getStPhone().toString());
```

Are you setting the values for StAddress,StPhone may be the get method returns null as u are initially not providing any values for these fields.

Please provide the stacktace of the exception

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities here;

```
1. StudentsInfo si = getInfo(username, rollno, class);
   // Check if getInfo is returning a non null student info object?

2. String ID = si.getInfo().get(i).getStId().toString();
   // Check for Student ID getStId()
   // get(i)  
   // getInfo()
```